# Nginx not able to find js files of react docker container

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx

I have nginx running on my host. It redirects to the docker container on port 5000 upon accessing /admin and on writing / it redirects to port 80.

Although the redirection is working, the js and css files are not being loaded by the react container. I can see the title of the page change to React container's title but the network tab in google shows 404 for all the js files.

What am I missing?

THE DOCKER FILE

```
FROM node as builder
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install && mkdir /react-ui && mv ./node_modules ./react-ui
WORKDIR /react-ui
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:alpine
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
# COPY ./build /var/www
COPY --from=builder /react-ui/build /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["nginx","-g","daemon off;"]
```

THE NGINX CONFIG INSIDE DOCKER

```
# auto detects a good number of processes to run
worker_processes auto;

#Provides the configuration file context in which the directives that affect connection processing are specified.
events {
    # Sets the maximum number of simultaneous connections that can be opened by a worker process.
    worker_connections 8000;
    # Tells the worker to accept multiple connections at a time
    multi_accept on;
}


http {
    # what times to include
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    # what is the default one
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    # Sets the path, format, and configuration for a buffered log write
    log_format compression '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
        '"$request" $status $upstream_addr '
        '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent"';

    server {
        # listen on port 80
        listen 5000;
        # save logs here
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log compression;

        # where the root here
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # what file to server as index
        index index.html index.htm;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to redirecting to index.html
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        # Media: images, icons, video, audio, HTC
        location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
          expires 1M;
          access_log off;
          add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Javascript and CSS files
        location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            expires 1y;
            access_log off;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        }

        # Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
        location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
        }
    }
}
```

NGINX ON HOST

```
location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
    }
```

Comment: i had a similar issue with docker-compose in the past, the main issue was that the file had a different structure inside the docket container so i needed to copy the file structure as well. Maybe it's the same for you? Anyway it will always help if you could provide code so we can see what might be wrong :)

Comment: Most likely a problem in your nginx config. Can you share it?